# Как передать php массив в sql?

Tags: php, javascript, sql, json

Добрый вечер! Есть HTML таблица, из которой конвертирую информацию в json, оттуда в php и далее в таблицу sql. Застряла на последнем этапе, не понимаю, как передать полученный массив в sql.
JS:

```
var convertTableToJson = function()
        {
            var rows = [];
            $('#table1 tr').each(function(i, n){
                var $row = $(n);
                rows.push({
                    Id:     $row.find('td:eq(0)').text(),
                    Name:   $row.find('td:eq(1)').text()
                });
            });
            return JSON.stringify(rows);
        };
    $(function(){
       console.log(convertTableToJson ());
    });

    $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "php/databasee.php",
          dataType:"json",
          data: {"user":convertTableToJson()}
      });
```

В консоль выводит это:

> [{"Id":"1","Name":"Enter the name"}]

, мне надо в таблицу SQL передать сами значения 1 и Enter the name. Но таблица HTML динамическая, то есть таких строк будет больше.
В php написала уже такое, но не работает:

```
<?php

$servername="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$database="project";
$conn=mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $database);
$array=$_POST['user'];
echo $array;
$par=json_decode($array);
if(is_array($par)){

    $sql = "INSERT INTO projectu (Id, Name) values ";
    $valuesArr = array();
    foreach($array as $row){

        $id= (int) $row['Id'];
        $name = mysqli_real_escape_string( $row['Name'] );
echo $id;
echo $name;
        $valuesArr[] = "('$id', '$name')";
    }

    $sql .= implode(',', $valuesArr);

    mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
}
?>
```

Ошибку такую выдает:

> **Warning**:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   **C:\Server\data\htdocs\project\php\databasee.php** on line
>   **20**

Подскажите пожалуйста!

Comment: Добрый вечер. Проверьте, что в $_POST. echo $array; - покажет ошибку.

Comment: У вас жуткая мешанина в коде и непонятно где и что хранится. Сначала берёте из POST и это декодируете, но не используете $par. Разберитесь и используйте отладку чтобы видеть значения в переменных во время исполнения.

Comment: Не слишком углублялся в ваш код, но если не ошибаюсь,$array у вас это json строчка которую вы декодируете при помощи json_decode, и результат декодирования, который является массивом, пишете в переменную $par. Так почему вы передаете в foreach именно $array а не $par?